# Centos 7, PHP 7.2 Permission denied via Apache2.4

Tags: php, mysql, apache

i can't log in to mysql via pdo when i try to execute connection to db via apache but on cli it works just fine

in `symfony 4.1 controller` i have inserted this string

```
new PDO('mysql:host=db;dbname=test_db', 'xyz', 'uzzzxxxx');
```

and it give Exception but on `Symfony4.1 command` the same line works and i can query db. 
What can cause this? Controller and command are in one bundle

Answer (score 1):

I believe for Apache you are looking for localhost as your host.

```
 new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test_db', 'xyz', 'uzzzxxxx');
```

While I'm unfamiliar with Symfony, it may be that either it uses different credentials or it may be that when  it detects an error, it sets it to localhost, whereas Apache does not.

Comment: I believe, php executed by Apache can't access host `db`, and the same code executed directly in cli don't have this limitations somehow

Answer (score 0):

You have to give Apache  enable writing to log files and file uploads as well? Let’s play nice with SELinux. And set the proper ownership and permissions

```
# Ownership
```

sudo chown apache:apache -R /data/www/html/sites/mysite
cd /data/www/html/sites/mysite

## File permissions, recursive

find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;

## Dir permissions, recursive

find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;

## SELinux serve files off Apache, resursive

sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t /data/www/html/sites/mysite -R

## Allow write only to specific dirs

sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /data/www/html/sites/mysite/logs -R
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /data/www/html/sites/mysite/uploads -R

> httpd_sys_content_t – for allowing Apache to serve these contents and httpd_sys_rw_content_t – for allowing Apache to write to those path.

That’s it! I enjoyed and you share!

Comment: I'll check your solution

Answer (score 0):

In my case at fault was SELinux by disabling it, now it works 
in case someone want to check there is tutorial 
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-disable-selinux-on-centos-7/